# after reload page IE is not retaining it's scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on a delete item function. Its working fine in all browsers but In IE fail to retain it's scroll position. I want to keep the same position after reload of the page

```
function _removeItem(element) {
    var $target = $(element),
        prodId = $target.data("id");
    something.call('something', {
        productId: prodId
    }).done(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe on page unload, you write script to record current scroll position, and on page load, you write script to scroll to the last recorded position.

Comment: Which version of IE? Is there asynchronous data being loaded also?

Comment: IE-11 and data is also asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
  }
});
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261611/4666994