# Page is getting scrolled to the top after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website is getting scrolled to the top of the screen once the page is loaded. How can i stop this behavior using javascript?

Say for example, i move to the bottom of the screen(i.e till footer) and refresh the page, i dont my screen to show any scrolling behavior during the page reload. But here once the page is reloaded it moves to the top of the screen.

Saving the window scroll top position and again resetting it on window.onLoad is making the page to scroll and position back. Which is not being accepted as a end user experience.

Please let me know if i can resolve this issue using javascript/CSS?

PFB the site,

```
http://www.millers.com.au/
```

Comment: I have checked your website. When i scroll to bottom and refresh again it remains there.So what's the issue?

Comment: @AlivetoDie,Once the page is loaded completely, it scrolls to the top the page, that is the issue.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261365/retain-scrollbar-position-even-after-reloading-using-javascript